# Behavior that is both recursive, and depends on other behaviors

Tags: haskell, recursion, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

My network looks like this:

```
ePhysics :: Event t ()
bPlayerForce :: Behavior t (Double,Double)
bPlayerPosition :: Behavior t (Double, Double)
```

`ePhysics` is fired repeatedly from a timer.
I'm having issues with defining `bPlayerPosition`. What I intend is that it will start at `(0,0)`, and whenever `ePhysics` is fired, `bPlayerPosition` will be recalculated using `bPlayerForce` as a parameter.

The problem is that in-order to specify an initial value I need to use `accumB`/`stepper` but they only work with events, and I can't get the force value from `bPlayerForce` since only behaviors can get the value of other behaviors (with `<*>`).

The alternative would be just using `<*>` but with that I have no initial value, so it becomes a meaningless infinite recursion:

```
let bPlayerPosition = pure calcPosition <*> bPlayerForce <*> bPlayerPosition
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Is there a way of getting a value out of a behavior without `<*>`? like, when `reactimate`ing or mapping an event? the issue of not being able to has been screwing with me constantly since the very start.
2. Would there be a more functional/frp way to do physics? (in general and the ones specific to the question)
3. How can I solve the presented problem?

Comment: Looks like you just need [`apply`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v:apply), a.k.a. `(<@>)`

Comment: A very FRP way to do physics involves `integral :: (VectorSpace v) => Behavior v -> Behavior v`, which reactive-banana does not provide, but which can be approximated (in essentially the way you describe here, but the meaning is the important thing!).

Comment: @luqui Could you elaborate on `apply`? I mean, I don't have any event relevant for its argument.
If reactive-banana isn't 100% perfectly suited for the task could you please suggest an FRP library that would be more complete for me (and hopefully one with `integral` you mentioned)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `apply` combinator, also called `<@>`, and its variant `<@` provide a way to sample a Behavior whenever an event happens.
2. Looks fine to me. The [Animation.hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples#animation) example does something similar. You have to approximate the integral by summing over discrete time steps, which are given by your `ePhysics` event.
3. Something along the lines of

   ```
   let bPlayerPosition = stepper (0,0) $
           (calcPosition <*> bPlayerForce <*> bPlayerPosition) <@ ePhysics
   ```